# Can I run a for loop inside a if statement

Tags: c

Code written in c language trying to get desired output but else condition is not running

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  if (i <= 10)
  {
    for (scanf("%d", &i);i<=10;i++)
    {
      printf("%d\n",i);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Please enter a valid number");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior. The `if` is testing a variable that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: but in this case `i` is uninitialized, so your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: I m wrirting down my code here but it is not accepted by rhis website .Don't know why

Comment: You need two loops: one loop to ask for the input and check if it's a valid number, then the second loop to print the numbers.

Comment: Write down the logic you want the program to perform before you write the code. Analyzing the logic of your code shows it cannot do what you intend it to do. Please expand your question with what the program is supposed to do, what it does instead, and what attempts you have made to correct the issue.

Comment: In this program i want to ask the user a number if he entered number bw 1 to 10 then i had to print all the number between the number entered by the user to 10 and if he enter number more than 10 then a message should print that invalid number

Comment: I'm wondering if a `do-while` loop is what you really want here.

Comment: but if i will apply do-while loop here then if user entered a invalid input then also printf() will do its task

Comment: What does your (now edited) question mean? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You are not initialized your variable named `i`. You must have to initialize it before using.

Comment: If you look at the `else` statement, he actually wants to test the user input. The code is completely inside-out.